# How to use LINQ to get data from List<string>[]

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization

I have this code which is working but I want to optimize.
As much as possible, I want to avoid using the **foreach** part. Is there a way to achieve this via LINQ? That is if LINQ is the better option that the loop?

```
        var collaborators = projects.Where(p => p.CollaboratingOrganisations != null
                                        && p.CollaboratingOrganisations.Count > 0)
                                    .Select(p => p.CollaboratingOrganisations).ToArray();
        List<string> collaboratingOrgNameList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var org in collaborators)
        {
            collaboratingOrgNameList.AddRange(org);
        }
```

Comment: Why was my question voted down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
  List<string> collaboratingOrgNameList = collaborators.SelectMany(s => s).ToList();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Now  I learned something new :)